# Ionic - Application does not have sufficient geolocation permissions

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I installed and set up Ionic native `cordova-plugin-geolocation` plugin. Everything worked fine, but today an error message appears from nowhere when debugging on my `Android 6` :

> PositionError {
>   code: 2, message: "application does not have sufficient geolocation  permissions."
>   }

I have no idea why this message appeared, except that my phone does not ask me anymore if I want to allow localization for this application.

`cordova-plugin-geolocation` plugin is up to date `v. 3.0.0`.

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: No I didn't! Still the same problem.

Comment: Is it specific for android 6 only?

Comment: Still you have not found out the solution? I am also currently stucked for long in this issue..

Answer (score 2):

Run following Command

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation --variable 
GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION="To locate you"
```